# Changing how output is printed to the console

Tags: r, pretty-print

When I print something directly to the console (type some variable name, such as `x`, rather than using the print function `print(x)`), I'd like it to print differently from the way that it normally prints. My idea is that the printing is done by some function. If that's the case, all I have to do is replace that function with a function of my own. However, I cannot figure out what the internal function that does the printing is.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
.real_cat = cat
cat = function(x) .real_cat("*** cat ***", x, "\n")

cat(2345)
2345    # no
```

Printing to console is not done via `cat`. What about `print`?

```
.real_print = print
print = function(x) .real_cat("*** print ***", x, "\n")
print(2345)
2345    # no
"hello" # no
I(2345) # yes
```

**Some** classes, like `AsIs`, are printed to console via `print`, but others, like `numeric` or `character` are not. :-(

```
c("print.numeric", "print.character", "print.AsIs", "print.default") %in% methods("print")
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Turns out `print` doesn't even have a separate method for printing `numeric` or `character`. Classes that have a `print` method are printed to the console using `print`. But classes that do not have a `print` method are not. Maybe they are printed using the `default` method?

```
print.default = function(x) .real_cat("*** print.default ***", x, "\n")
print.default(2345)
2345    # no
"hello" # no
```

No.

Maybe if I define a method for numeric, **then** it will print it using that method?

```
print.numeric = function(x) .real_cat("*** print.numeric ***", x, "\n")
print.numeric(2345)
2345    # no

print.character = function(x) .real_cat("*** print.character ***", x, "\n")
print.character("hello")
"hello" # no
```

Here is where I get stuck. I cannot figure out any way to have some basic classes like `numeric` or `character` print out directly to console using my own print function.

If this helps, here is the reason that I want to do this. I am writing a package to pretty-print values (https://github.com/prettyprint/prettyprint). Too many times, the output of an analysis is too hard to read, and therefore understand. Yes, you can make it pretty using `format`, `signif`, and `round`, and that's basically what the package already does for you in the background.

I would like to make pretty-printing as easy as possible for the user. At this point, they have to call my pretty-print function (`pp(x)`). I'd like to play around with giving the user the option to have the result pretty print automatically. (I would print both the non-pretty and the pretty version of the value, to make sure nothing is lost in the prettifying.)

Comment: A workaround with implicit classes would be to add a class attribute to the object and use a `print` method. E.g. `print.numeric = function(x, ...) cat("numeric: \n", unclass(x), "\n"); xx = c(1, 2, 3); xx; attr(xx, "class") = "numeric"; xx`. Or you could define your own "class" and its `print` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this comment in [the source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/print.c):

```
 *  print.default()  ->  do_printdefault (with call tree below)
 *
 *  auto-printing   ->  PrintValueEnv
 *                      -> PrintValueRec
 *                      -> call print() for objects
 *  Note that auto-printing does not call print.default.
 *  PrintValue, R_PV are similar to auto-printing.
 *
 *  do_printdefault
 *  -> PrintDefaults
 *  -> CustomPrintValue
 *      -> PrintValueRec
 *          -> __ITSELF__  (recursion)
 *          -> PrintGenericVector   -> PrintValueRec  (recursion)
 *          -> printList            -> PrintValueRec  (recursion)
 *          -> printAttributes      -> PrintValueRec  (recursion)
 *          -> PrintExpression
 *          -> printVector      >>>>> ./printvector.c
 *          -> printNamedVector >>>>> ./printvector.c
 *          -> printMatrix      >>>>> ./printarray.c
 *          -> printArray       >>>>> ./printarray.c
```

Consequently, auto-printing can only involve method dispatch for explicit classes (with a class attribute, a.k.a. objects). I assume a `numeric` is handled by `printVector`. Please check this yourself.

`I` adds a class `AsIs` (creating an object) and then `print.AsIs` is dispatched:

```
class(I(3))
#[1] "AsIs"
```

Comment: I see here https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/printvector.c a C function called `printVector`. How do I figure out which R function calls it?

Comment: This is all handled at the C level. Unless you are printing an object, auto-printing does not involve R functions.