# Defining custom print methods for arrays and atomic vectors

Tags: r, r-s3

I would like to define a different print method for arrays, but I’m afraid I’m not understanding something about S3 dispach. My custom print method is called if I call print(x) explicitly, but is not called if I just type x at the console. However, if I define a custom S3 class, then the appropriate print method is called.

A similar thing happens if I try to define a method for print.numeric

Here is a minimal example:

```
print.array <- function(x, ...) cat("Hi!\n")

x <- array(1:8, c(2,2,2) )

print(x) # the print method defined above is called
# Hi!
x        # the print method defined above is NOT called
```

Does anyone have any insights into what is happening? What function is actually doing the printing when just `x` is evaluated at the console?

Comment: This probably has to do with [`auto-printing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638830/496488) occurring when you type the bare object name for an object class that has an auto-print method defined. A comment in the linked answer implies that you can't change this in R, as it's handled at the C level. If you change your function name to `print.array2` and then do `class(x) = "array2"; x` you'll see that your new `array2` `print` method is called, even when you type the bare object name in the console. But that's not all that helpful unless you're creating a new object class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the S3 method in a `NAMESPACE` (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces)) in an extension structure (package) as follows:

```
export(print.array)
S3method(print, array)
```

I suggest you use `devtools` to create your "package" (that can easily contain only your `print.array` function), you'll find some excellent resources [here](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in my hands (which, as pointed out in the comment, might be expected).